# extending context menu in windows Mobile Contact

Tags: windows-mobile, compact-framework, opennetcf

i want to extend contact context menu in windows mobile. when a user right clicks on a contact with dial and other feature i want to extend and add my own item to execute my custom program or so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i found another [example](http://www.ceveni.com/2009/10/sample-code-for-context-menu-in-c.html) here i think this should work for you

```
// Initialize the below code snippet in the beginning of the class
internal struct SHRGINFO
{
public int cbSize;
public IntPtr hwndClient;
public int ptDownX;
public int ptDownY;
public SHRGFLags dwFlags;
}

[Flags]
internal enum SHRGFLags
{
SHRG_RETURNCMD = 0x00000001,
SHRG_NOTIFYPARENT = 0x00000002,
SHRG_LONGDELAY = 0x00000008,
SHRG_NOANIMATION = 0x00000010,
}
[DllImport("aygshell")]
extern private static int SHRecognizeGesture(ref SHRGINFO shr);

[DllImport("coredll.dll", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern IntPtr GetActiveWindow();


//call the showContMenu() method in Mouseup or MouseDown event
public void showContMenu(int x, int y)
{
SHRGINFO shr = new SHRGINFO();
shr.cbSize = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(SHRGINFO));
shr.dwFlags = SHRGFLags.SHRG_RETURNCMD;
shr.ptDownX = x;
shr.ptDownY = y;
shr.hwndClient = GetActiveWindow();

int ret = SHRecognizeGesture(ref shr);

if (ret == 1000)
contextMenu1.Show(this, new System.Drawing.Point(x, y));

}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you install the [Windows Mobile 5 SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/Downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=83a52af2-f524-4ec5-9155-717cbe5d25ed&displaylang=en), you will find some relevant samples:

C:\Program Files\Windows Mobile 5.0 SDK\Samples\Pocket PC\CPP\Win32

- Callingcard
- InboxMenuExtensibility
- ReadViewMenuExt